# Why did Whispers try to lobotomize Nomi instead of meeting her?

Tags: sense8

In the TV series Sense 8, we learn from Jonas and Will's conversation that any sensate outside the cluster needs to make eye contact with a person to be able to talk to him/her the way sensates inside a cluster do. Once Whispers makes eye contact with any person in a cluster he is able to hunt the cluster using that one person.

After Riley was captured, Whispers made his way to Iceland to meet her so as to make eye contact and then hunt the cluster. Why didn't he attempt the same thing with Nomi? It was clearly easier then, without Nomi and Will trying to ruin his plan. So why did BPO/Whispers try to lobotomize Nomi? Am I missing something here. Metzger was working for BPO and Whispers.

Once a person is knocked out, sensates cannot contact him/her. My understanding is lobotomizing the sensates makes them lose their power and connection with the cluster. So Nomi wont be any help to Whispers post the operation.

Answer (score 4):

*Spoilers below.*

**In-Universe:**

As we see with Nyles Bolger in [Episode 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense8_(season_1)#Episodes), being lobotomized is not mutually exclusive with being under Whisper's control.  Was Nyles exposed to Whispers before his lobotomy, or after?  We don't know... but we do see Whispers using someone who has been lobotomized through the same doctor that Nomi was subject to.  QED, that's a known working path including *both* lobotomy and whisperotomy.

**Out-of-Universe**

You don't put all of your cards on the table at the very beginning... and Whispers' eye-fu was being saved up for the climactic Icelandic arc.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that Nomi was already in the hospital for her accident was likely too convenient to pass up. In the end, the mission of BPO is to destroy sensates. Depriving them of their shared abilities (and creating soldiers, as in Nyles) is as important as tracking down more. And with Jonas actively interacting with the new cluster, Whispers likely felt he had enough leads to go on.

Answer (score 1):

I look at it like a priorities situation. While they may have just found out about Nomi. They were more concerned that they had just captured Jonas who had been a thorn in their side for years with intimate knowledge of their organization. While Nomi didn't even know what a sensate was. In this instance Jonas would take priority.

Answer (score 0):

It was Dr.Metzger that tried to operate on Nomi's brain, before Will helped them escape from the medical gurney.

Answer (score 0):

The Chairman was controlling the Dr. If the lobotomy was done on Nomi, then Whispers wouldn't know about her or be able to get to her in time. Plus her brain scans showed she was just starting to turn Sensate.  The chairman just wanted all Sensate to die. But Whispers had his own goal.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  So your point is that it wasn't Whispers that was responsible for the (attempted) lobotomy?  That might make sense, but it's not entirely clear from your answer.